# How can you compare two RippleDrawables?

Tags: android, android-espresso, rippledrawable

I am using android `Espresso`. I would like to know how I can check if the `drawable` being used on a view is the same as what should be used as stated in the specs. I am trying to compare the `ConstantStates` of the `drawable` use on the `view`, and the one in the Resources, but I am not getting anywhere.

Is there a way to do this? Or is this check entirely not needed when it comes to automated testing?

Answer (score 0):

For comparing two images I already used this code:

```
public class ImageComparator {

public static Matcher<View> withImageResource(final int imageResourceId) {
return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

@Override
public void describeTo(Description description) {
description.appendText("with drawable from resource id: " + imageResourceId);
}

@Override
public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
Drawable actualDrawable = ((ImageView) view).getDrawable();
final Drawable correctDrawable = view.getResources().getDrawable(imageResourceId);
if (actualDrawable == null) {
return correctDrawable == null;
}
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
return areImagesTheSameAfterSdk21(actualDrawable, correctDrawable);
} else {
return areImagesTheSameBeforeSdk21(actualDrawable, correctDrawable);
}
}
};
}

protected static boolean areImagesTheSameBeforeSdk21(Drawable actualDrawable,
Drawable correctDrawable) {
Drawable.ConstantState actualDrawableConstantState = actualDrawable.getConstantState();
Drawable.ConstantState correctDrawableConstantState = correctDrawable.getConstantState();
return actualDrawableConstantState.equals(correctDrawableConstantState);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
protected static boolean areImagesTheSameAfterSdk21(Drawable actualDrawable,
Drawable correctDrawable) {
Bitmap correctBitmap = drawableToBitmap(correctDrawable);
Bitmap actualBitmap = drawableToBitmap(actualDrawable);

return correctBitmap.sameAs(actualBitmap);
}

private static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
}

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap
.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(),
Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);

return bitmap;
}
}
```

Hope it will help